# Angular 6 calling method and asigning value to variable inside *ngFor

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular2-template

I want to call a method inside `ngFor` and want to assign the return value to a local variable. I tried this approach:

```
<div *ngFor="let card of partNumberPlanningCards; let i = index" class="partnumber-basic-card">
<div 
  *ngFor="let scope of containerScopeLineItems; let lineItem = getOperatingWeightBy(scope.containerScopeId, card.typeId)">
   </div>
 </div>
```

But it's showing this error:

```
Parser Error: Unexpected token (, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 74 in [let scope of containerScopeLineItems; let lineItem = getOperatingWeightBy(scope.containerScopeId, card.typeId)] in ng
```

Comment: Where is your containerScopeLineItems? It's better to filter or use directives here.

Comment: a better method here would be to modify your array to be the items you'd want them to be when it needs to be done.

Answer (score 1):

You can store `function` returned value in any of the `attribute` of `element` and use the `element` reference to get value.

```
<div *ngFor="let card of partNumberPlanningCards; let i = index" class="partnumber-basic-card">
    <div *ngFor="let scope of containerScopeLineItems" #lineItem [title]="getOperatingWeightBy(scope.containerScopeId, card.typeId)">

        {{lineItem.title}}

    </div>
</div>
```

Here `title` has been used but you can use any of valid attribute of element.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do here? Calling a function within ngFor to update DOM is certainly a bad practice to do.

As it looks, you want to filter based on the containerScopeId and typeId, you could simply do this and assign to a variable in the component.ts level rather than calling a function in the template.

Just declare a variable lineItem and use **`array.find()`** with your conditions to get the matching item.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps you. But just tried something.. You can create a `ng-template` and use `ng-container` to display the template.

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let card of partNumberPlanningCards;" class="partnumber-basic-card">
{{card?.typeId}}
<div *ngFor="let scope of containerScopeLineItems;">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="eng; context: getOperatingWeightBy(card.typeId, scope.containerScopeId)"></ng-container>
    {{scope?.containerScopeId}}
</div>
```

`<ng-template #eng let-obj='value'>
    {{obj}}
</ng-template>`

TS:

`export class AppComponent {`

```
partNumberPlanningCards = [
    {typeId : 'xx'}
]

containerScopeLineItems = [
    {containerScopeId : 2}
];

getOperatingWeightBy(a,b){
    return {value:a+b};
}
```

`}`

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngfor-loop